# How make a social share goal widget in wordpress

Tags: api, wordpress, wordpress-theming, social-networking

I need to make a share goal widget for wordpress like this website - https://www.sevenly.org/  Can any one tell me how to accomplish this. Any plugins or any ways to get the total number of share of a specified period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a plugin that has this functionality at the moment, so you may have to get your hands dirty writing code. [Here's a tutorial on how to get the number of shares](http://www.internoetics.com/2012/05/16/count-shares-to-facebook-twitter-linkedin-googleplus/) with some code that works in Wordpress. I think this is a good idea for a plugin developer.